# Restrict request to Android and Iphone App only?

Tags: android, ios, asp.net, iphone

I have a ASP.NET/IIS server. I want to restrict my server to only accept request from Android and Iphone(IOS) applications. I have heard about HMAC. Can HMAC help me?

Comment: "Can HMAC help me". No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, HMAC won't do what you want. Your best solution would be to use a challenge response scheme (assuming it is an android/iOS mobile app accessing your server). Have obscured code in your app to respond to a challenge request using a hidden algorithm. An attacker could decompile the app, but it is the closest solution to what he/she is requesting.

If the communication is through a mobile webpage then this approach won't work.

Like other answers have said, you can't trust user input (headers). They are trivial to spoof.

Answer (score 2):

[HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hmac) is a cryptographic concept for assuring the integrity and source (authentication) of information.  This isn't really applicable for what you are trying to do.

Really, there's no way to ensure a request is coming from a specific platform, this is because the host receives this information from the client.  A client can send whatever information it wants by manipulating (spoofing) the HTTP Headers, specifically the [User-Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) field.

Bottom line, you can not trust user (client) supplied information.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, impossible.
In practice, you can use some platform specific tricks like for android.
1. Push an expiring token from GCM https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html to device.
2. The request should contain the token.

The token can be time dependent, android id dependent or both.
In such case, the person needs a device to get the token and send the requests.
At least, you will know who is making the requests and can block the person if needed.